# Script used to find and split the chapters between 2 and 6 (x and n) of all m4b files in directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to use a script to find and split the chapters between 2 and 6 (x and n) of all m4b files in directory.

This code splits m4b files out into chapters when run `bash m4b-split.sh *.m4b`

```
#!/bin/bash
# used to find and split all m4b files in directory by chapter and convert them to mp3 files
# to run type "bash m4b-split.sh *.m4b"

# Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 1290.013333
# first _ _ start _ end
currentdir=$(pwd) #get current directory

#: '
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    for f in *.m4b # only look for m4b files
    do
        #fn=`echo "$1" | cut -d'.' -f1` #get just the filename no extension
        fn=$(basename "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1) #get just the filename no extension
        echo "($fn)"
        splitdirname="$currentdir/final-split-$fn" #sub directory with correct names
        mkdir -p "$splitdirname" #make split directory
        echo "$splitdirname/$chapter-$fn.mp3"
        ffmpeg -i "$1" 2> tmp.txt

        while read -r first _ _ start _ end; do
            if [[ $first = Chapter ]]; then
                read -r # discard line with Metadata:
                read -r _ _ chapter

                ffmpeg -vsync 2 -i "$1" -ss "${start%?}" -to "$end" -metadata title="$chapter $fn" -metadata track="$chapter" -vn -ar 22050 -ac 1 -ab 128 -f mp3 "$splitdirname/$chapter-$fn.mp3" </dev/null
            fi
        done <tmp.txt

        rm tmp.txt
        shift
    done
done
#'
```

I tried the code below but when run `bash m4b-split.sh *.m4b` i get **m4b-split.sh: line 25: ((: Opening Credits: syntax error in expression (error token is "Credits")**

#### Update 1:

It looks like I need to get the chapters as numbers / as a numerical instead of just chapters since I need to compare the chapter numbers.  **How can I get the chapter numbers and compare them so it will only split them between 2 and 6 (x and n) of all m4b files in directory?**

```
#!/bin/bash
# use a script to find and split the chapters between 2 and 6 (x and n) of all m4b files in directory
# to run type "bash m4b-split.sh *.m4b"

# Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 1290.013333
# first _ _ start _ end
currentdir=$(pwd) #get current directory

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    for f in *.m4b # only look for m4b files
    do
        fn=$(basename "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1) #get just the filename no extension
        echo "($fn)"
        splitdirname="$currentdir/final-split-$fn" #sub directory with correct names
        mkdir -p "$splitdirname" #make split directory
        echo "$splitdirname/$chapter-$fn.mp3"
        ffmpeg -i "$1" 2> tmp.txt

        while read -r first _ _ start _ end; do
            if [[ $first = Chapter ]]; then
                read -r # discard line with Metadata:
                read -r _ _ chapter

                # Only process chapters 2-6
                if ((chapter >= 2 && chapter <= 6)); then
                    ffmpeg -vsync 2 -i "$1" -ss "${start%?}" -to "$end" -metadata title="$chapter $fn" -metadata track="$chapter" -vn -ar 22050 -ac 1 -ab 128 -f mp3 "$splitdirname/$chapter-$fn.mp3" </dev/null
                fi

            fi
        done <tmp.txt

        rm tmp.txt
        shift
    done
done
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @waltinator I just used it, it said '
Line 23:
read # discard line with Metadata:
^-- SC2162 (info): read without -r will mangle backslashes.
 
Line 24:
read _ _ chapter
^-- SC2162 (info): read without -r will mangle backslashes.'

I added '-r' but that had the same error in the same line

Comment: The error message suggests that `read _ _ chapter` is reading something you don't expect - in particular that variable `credits` is assigned the value `Opening Credits` instead of a (presumably) numeric value. One possible gotcha is that `ffmpeg` may be consuming part of the redirected standard input `<tmp.txt`: see for example [Unexpected output from ffmpeg in bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374787/unexpected-output-from-ffmpeg-in-bash-script)

Comment: ... sorry I meant "variable `chapter`" of course

Comment: I looked at that link ou posted and added the `-nostdin` option but that didn't work.

Comment: If you have new information, [edit] your question. Format it properly. As is (added in Add Comment), it is not readable. Also, Add Comment is for US to ask YOU for information that, addedcto YOUR Question,  will make it more likely to be answered.

Comment: @waltinator ok I formatted the question and updated it with text